# how to maintain friend requests data in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

I have a requirement in my app where one user can send the friend request to another user. We use SQL Server database as the backend. The structure of the table is like this.

```
CREATE TABLE FriendStatus
(FriendStatusId BIGINT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
FromUserId BIGINT,
ToUserId BIGINT,
StatusId TINYINT,
SentTime DATETIME2,
ResponseTime DATETIME2);
```

I have few questions related to this:
If user A sends a friend request to user B, then the friend request from user B to User A should still valid ? I feel that should be the case, let me know if there is a better way of handling this ?

Is it a good idea to store the users data in a separate table called friends table once User b approves user A friend request  ? And Once User B approves User A request then two records needs to be inserted into the friends table with col1 containing user A and col2 containing user B .At the same time should we also insert a record with User B in col1 and USer A in col2 ? Or two records are unnecessary ?

Comment: You're asking us what your business rules are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a few examples from Facebook to answer.

> If user A sends a friend request to user B, then the friend request
>   from user B to User A should still valid?

No, a dialog box appears `You have already recieved a Friend Request from {name}`. Also from B's view, The link to `Send Friend Request` to A should be changed to `Respond to friend request` with a respective code.

> Is it a good idea to store the users data in a separate table called friends...?

No, one record is enough. Additionally you can have a new column to maintain status `status={blocked|friends|pending}`

Well thats my idea. You are free since the application is yours. Think as a user too.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it a good idea to store the users data in a separate table called friends table once User b approves user A friend request ?

No, it's almost never a good idea to duplicate data in your database.  You can get anomalies where the same data in two places has two different values.  Which value is the correct value?

Here's one way to maintain the relationship

```
User
----
User ID
User Name
...

Friend
------
User ID 1
User ID 2
...
```

In the Friend table, the primary key is (User ID 1, User ID 2).  You would also have a unique index on (User ID 2, User ID 1).  It's up to you if you want to have one row or two rows for each relationship.

One row means you have to do two SELECTS with a UNION.  One SELECT using the primary key and one SELECT using the unique index.

Two rows means you do a SELECT using the primary key.

You have the same one row / two row choice with the FriendRequest table.

```
FriendRequest
-------------
User ID 1
User ID 2
Status
Sent Time Stamp
Accepted Time Stamp
...
```

You can have one row or two rows for each request.  In this case, I'd prefer the one row because I could determine which user initiated the friend request.